# Python: Look for a value/data in the entire excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas

I have to compare data present in the two excel sheets and insert the difference in the third sheet.

I am aware that I have to do the comparison twice i.e. `file1!=file2` and `file2!=file1`.

`Q1:` Is there a way that only one step finds the difference in the two files?

So far I have written the below code and its working also:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('/Users/Testing/Data1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('/Users/Testing/Data2.xlsx')

difference = df1[df1!=df2]
print(difference)
```

Sample data:

```
Data1:

S.No ID    Name   RegionName   RegionCode
 1.  191  Roger   EU           76
 2.  334  Martin  TT           09
 3.  442  Steven  YU           89
 4.  776  Georgee TT           09


Data2:

S.No ID    Name   RegionName   RegionCode
01.  111  Ralph   EU           76
02.  254  Luthur  SE           19
03.  564  Todd    OO           67
04.  776  Georgee TT           09
```

Difference I am getting is:

```
S.No ID    Name   RegionName   RegionCode
 01.  191  Roger   EU           76
 02.  334  Martin  TT           09
 03.  442  Steven  YU           89
 04.  776  Georgee TT           09
 05.  111  Ralph   EU           76
 06.  254  Luthur  SE           19
 07.  564  Todd    OO           67
 08.  776  Georgee TT           09
```

Expected result is:

```
S.No ID    Name   RegionName   RegionCode
01   191  Roger    EU           76
02   334  Martin   TT           09
03   442  Steven   YU           89
04   254  Luthur   SE           19 
05   564  Todd     OO           67
06   111  Ralph    EU           76

Q2:
```

How can I get the above result? The requirement is to search and store the value which is present in only one file(e.g.. Data1) and not in the other(e.g. Data2).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What are the `df3` and `df4` variables?

Comment: @HaskarP Sorry that was by mistake. I have corrected it.

Comment: If given an ID , the Name , RegionName , RegionCode are the same , instead of comparing the records , you could just compare the two ID columns. Use set operations to get the required I'D and extract them from the dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can concat and drop_duplicates:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
new_df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

    S.No    ID      Name    RegionName  RegionCode
0   1.0      191    Roger   EU           76
1   2.0      334    Martin  TT           9
2   3.0      442    Steven  YU           89
0   1.0      111    Ralph   EU          76
1   2.0      254    Luthur  SE          19
2   3.0      564    Todd    OO           67
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is not helping out. I have tried to clarify the requirement more in the question.

Comment: @Alpha this produces your expected output.

Comment: @Alpha The requirement is to capture the values(eg. Data1) which are not present in another file(eg. Data2). From your logic, I will get all the values while the duplicates are dropped. I need the values/data which are present in only file and not in the other.

Comment: @alpha correct. That is why you concatenate your two dataframes into one dataframe and then drop duplicates. What is left are the unique rows that exist in one dataframe or the other. Any row that exist in both dataframes is dropped. You set keep to false so it drops all the rows that are duplicated.